# Is a time-sharing system also a multi-processing system?

Tags: operating-system, theory, job-scheduling

I am studying Operating Systems as a Computing module.

My question: Is a time-sharing system also a multi-processing system?

I'm aware that time-sharing systems allow processor time to be shared among multiple users, and multiprocessing refers to executing multiple processes at the same time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said the multiprocessing OS allows simultaneous execution of several processes. Simultaneous doesn't necessary mean that they run at the same time but that the OS maintain the execution of several processes (the processes can be interrupted in order to continue the execution of some other process). 
The Time-Sharing OS divides the time in quantums in order to share resources among processes. So, it is needed exactly to allow the execution of several processes. In this sense it is also a Multi-Processing system